# App Display Issue on Android Phone: Limited Screen Visibility

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

Problem:
App only shows in 10% of my screen; it shows in the corner of my Android phone. All screens are affected like this. The app works perfectly on Windows. The app shows on the entire window when I run on Windows 10. I exported the app using buildozer on Google Collab.

Tried:
I tried changing the Kivy version, switching to other screens, using another phone, using Kivymd instead of Kivy and vice-versa. I also tried exporting a simpler app which shows the full screen.

The following images show what the app looks like on my Android device:

[Screen on android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpI1i.jpg)

[Second screen on android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hvFQ.jpg)

This is a summary of my code:

```py
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFloatingActionButton
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
import kivy
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
import os
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
import sqlite3
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, screen_manager, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen_manager = screen_manager


        layout = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing=10, padding=50)

        self.username = TextInput(hint_text="Username", size_hint=(1, None), height='40dp')
        layout.add_widget(self.username)

        self.password = TextInput(
            hint_text="Password", password=True, size_hint=(1, None), height='40dp')
        layout.add_widget(self.password)

        login_button = Button(text="Login", size_hint=(1, None), height='40dp')
        login_button.bind(on_release=self.login)
        layout.add_widget(login_button)

        self.message_label = MDLabel(halign='center', valign='top', size_hint=(1, None), height='40dp')
        layout.add_widget(self.message_label)
        self.add_widget(layout)

    def login(self, instance):
        print("pressed")
        username = self.username.text
        password = self.password.text

        users = {
            "Torkyo": "*****",
            "Menzi": "*****",
            "": "", #Driver1 Allahakba
            "Sakhile": "****",
            "Andre": "****"
        }

        if username in users and users[username] == password:
            if username == "Torkyo":
                self.parent.parent.current = 'torkyo_screen'
            elif username == "Menzi":
                self.parent.parent.current = 'menzi_screen'
            elif username == "":
                self.screen_manager.current = 'dirisa_screen'
            elif username == "Sakhile":
                self.parent.parent.current = 'manager_screen'
            elif username == "Andre":
                self.parent.parent.current = 'andre_screen'

class LoginApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        login_screen = LoginScreen(sm, name='login_screen')
        sm.add_widget(login_screen)
        sm.add_widget(TorkyoScreen(sm, name='torkyo_screen'))
        sm.add_widget(Driver1Screen(sm, name='dirisa_screen'))
        sm.add_widget(AndreScreen(sm, name='andre_screen'))
        sm.add_widget(MenziScreen(sm, name='menzi_screen'))
        sm.add_widget(CustomerManagementScreen(sm,
                                               name='Customer_Management_screen'))
        sm.add_widget(TorkyoCustomerDetailsScreen(
            sm, name='torkyo_customer_details_screen'))
        sm.add_widget(AndreCustomerDetailsScreen(sm,
                                                 name="customer_details_andre"))
        return sm

    def login(self):
        self.root.ids.login_screen.login(None)


class PopupWindow(Popup):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Window.size = (300, 200)
    LoginApp().run()
```

My original code is 1045 lines long.

I also added this:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', 'auto')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 'auto')
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')
```

In my buildozer spec file I tried:

```
fullscreen = True
```

All of the above didn't work.
Any help is appreciated.